# Finding multiple maxima for dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max

I'm trying to return all maximum values from a dictionary of lists.

```
my_dict = { 111: [50, 2, 34], 122: [50 , 4, 45], 133: [40, 1, 12], 144: [20, 5, 7]}

maxima = max(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

This is only returning '122', rather than both '111' and '122'. How can I modify this to return both keys?

Comment: Although this is not the answer, lists, tuples, etc. are compared **lexicographically**.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe this is what you want? This also keeps track of the max values for every key in my_dict.

```
maxima = {}
my_dict = { 111: [50, 2, 34], 122: [50 , 4, 45], 133: [40, 1, 12], 144: [20, 5, 7]}

for key in my_dict:
    maxima[key] = max(my_dict[key])

max_keys = [key for key in maxima if maxima[key] == max(maxima.values())]
print max_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort your list according to the max of items in the list you could do:

```
print(sorted(my_dict.keys(),key=lambda x: max(my_dict[x])))
```

You get `[144, 133, 122, 111]` but that wouldn't tell you which keys bear the highest value in their associated list.

So you have to perform that in 2 steps:

- compute maximum value of all values in lists
- extract the keys matching the lists containing this value

like this for instance:

```
my_dict = { 111: [50, 2, 34], 122: [50 , 4, 45], 133: [40, 1, 12], 144: [20, 5, 7]}

max_value = max(x for l in my_dict.values() for x in l) # flat max of values
```

or if you want to compute the max on a particular value given its position, for instance the first one:

```
max_value = max(l[0] for l in my_dict.values())
```

then extract from dict with filter:

```
print([k for k,v in my_dict.items() if max_value in v]) # keys whose value contain the max
```

result:

```
[122, 111]
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you. I realized I had an incorrect dictionary. I'm trying to focus on the first value in the list, rather than any number. The case above, nothing is > 50, so not a problem. Can you point me in the direction to learn how to focus on a specific value in the list?

Comment: it's even simpler that way. check my edit.

Comment: Thank you, again. Do you know any resources that I can use to learn this as well as you do? It's still a bit over my head. This is the last step of my code I need to produce a prototype and I've been stuck for a while.

Comment: I dunno. check Q&A on SO and read a lot on python basic structures & list comprehensions. Also practice a lot and check codereview.stackexchange.com to see how average code is criticized & improved, with explanations. Practice & practice.